# How do I transitively reference external files with serverless?

Tags: serverless-framework

I'm trying to do some transitive file references in my `serverless.yml`, but it seems like `serverless` always resolves references based on the `serverless.yml` file regardless of where other referenced files live.
Example:

`serverless.yml`:

```
...
resources:
  - ${file(./cloud-formation-resources/my-dashboard.yml)}
```

`./cloud-formation-resources/my-dashboard.yml`:

```
Resources:
  MyDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties:
      DashboardName: My
      DashboardBody: ${file(./cloud-formation-resources/dashboard-body-my.js):dashboardBodyMy}
```

`./cloud-formation-resources/dashboard-body-my.js`:

```
module.exports.dashboardBodyMy = (serverless) => {
 const fsPromises = require('fs').promises
 return fsPromises.readFile('./cloud-formation-resources/dashboard-body-my.json', 'utf-8')
};
```

`./cloud-formation-resources/dashboard-body-my.json`:

```
{
    "widgets": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

Am I supposed to put all my resource files in the same directory as my `serverless.yml`? The only [reference](https://epsagon.com/blog/how-to-package-external-code-in-aws-lambda-using-serverless-framework/) I've found about this is:

> The popular Serverless Framework is built to deploy only files inside the directory in which the serverless.yml file is contained.
>
> This limitation is probably by design — all the external code your Lambda needs can be usually included with a package manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serverless framework does assume that all included files should be under the same directory as `serverless.yml`, but it is common in many scenarios that external files are needed.

For that, you can use the [serverless-package-external](https://github.com/epsagon/serverless-package-external) plugin to easily add links to these files (you can read more about that in the same [blog post](https://epsagon.com/blog/how-to-package-external-code-in-aws-lambda-using-serverless-framework/) you referenced).

Comment: Do you know why serverless wants everything in a flat structure? Can you point to some documentation?

Comment: But you can reference another file in relation to the particular yml. If you have a project with a structure like this:
```
/database/serverless.yml
common-configs-serverless.yml
```
you would reference inside the serverless.yml with something like this: `${file(../common-configs-serverless.yml)`

not necessarily flat

Comment: I don't know about official docs, but I think the reason is that usually, a package manager (like 'npm') should be responsible for adding external files.
Referencing another file is possible, but it won't add the file to the deployment.